# Can I visit Ireland if I’ve voluntarily left the UK?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, ireland, removal

I left the UK voluntarily last year and have been given notice that I am not allowed to renter the UK for another 2-5 years.

However, nothing is mentioned about Ireland. I have a couple of friends and family in Ireland and I'm hoping to visit them this year, would I be able to seeing as I’m not allowed in the UK?

Additionally,

Would I still be denied entry if I applied for a student or work visa to either Ireland or the UK?

When I signed the documents to leave the UK it was against my will (my parents decision) and so as a result my education is still in complete. Would there be any other way to carry my A levels as per English curriculum seeing as I’m prohibited from entering the UK?

Comment: What was the reason for your voluntary departure? https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/606970/GI-Re-entry-bans-v7.pdf

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't count on it.

The UK and Irish visa authorities, though technically separate, do heavily share information and collaborate to avoid potentially troublesome visitors.

If you're trying for a visa on arrival then expect to be subject to intense questioning and have to prove yourself to the Irish border guards.

However, you are not banned from Ireland, if you apply for a visa in advance this might not be an automatic rejection.